# Hooking up into OS shutdown event in .NET WPF-Application on Win7 x64?

Tags: .net, wpf, events, system-shutdown, shutdown-hook

This seems to be mission impossible?
According to the comments on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx , others also have trouble archieving it.

Which event is the best one to use? Session.Ending? Exit?

Thanks for any hint!
Sascha

Comment: Just a guess, but what about [Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.shutdownstarted.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

may be [Application.SessionEnding Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.sessionending.aspx)?